# Transform string into Git branch name format with Bash

Tags: bash, git, shell, sh, tr

Lazy programmer here, I'm making a simple shell script that takes a branch name from the user input, transforms that name into proper format and creates new branch locally, then pushes it to the remote.

So the goal is to transform a string e.g. 'Mary had a little lamb' into 'mary-had-a-little-lamb', removing all characters that aren't digits or letters along the way as well as replacing all spaces, single or multiple, with -.

I have a working solution but it looks pretty ugly to me, how can I improve it?

Also, is there a way to check if the specified branch already exists locally and only proceed if it doesn't?

```
#!/bin/bash
currentBranch=$(git branch --show-current)
echo "Checking out from branch $currentBranch"
echo "Enter new branch name:"
read branchName
branchName=$(echo $branchName | tr -d ':-') #remove special characters
branchName=$(echo $branchName | tr -s ' ') #replace multiple spaces with one
branchName=$(echo $branchName | tr ' ' '-') #replace spaces with -
branchName=${branchName,,}

echo "Checking out new branch $branchName..."
git checkout -b $branchName
echo "Pushing new branch $branchName to the remote..."
git push origin $branchName
```

Comment: Also see [git check-ref-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Bash's built-in string substitution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Take this for a test
branch_name='foo bar    baz:: ::: qux----corge'

# Need extglob for the pattern to replace
shopt -s extglob

# Do the substition with extglob pattern
#san_branch_name="${branch_name//+([[:punct:][:space:]-])/-}"
# this is a shorter filter for valid git identifiers
san_branch_name="${branch_name//+([^[:alnum:]])/-}"


# For debug purposes
declare -p branch_name san_branch_name
```

Actual output:

```sh
declare -- branch_name="foo bar    baz:: ::: qux----corge"
declare -- san_branch_name="foo-bar-baz-qux-corge"
```

Comment: This works, thanks, except that ' - ' gets turned into '---' so I need to squeeze that.

Comment: @PaulJK I improved the pattern to also reduce multiple dashes `-` to only one and replace all punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use sed in order to sanitize you branch name by `sed` as follow:

```
sanitized_branch_name=$(echo ${branchName} | sed -E 's/\s+/\s/g' | sed -E 's/[\s:]/\-/g')
```

About how to check branch it is enough:

```
if git branch -a | grep $sanitized_branch_name 2>& 1>/dev/null; then
  echo "${sanitized_branch_name} branch exists!"
fi
```

**Edit (example output):**

```
$ branchName="antonio  petri:cca"

$ echo ${branchName} | sed -E 's/\s+/\s/g' | sed -E 's/[\s:]/\-/g'

antonio-petri-cca
```

Comment: Getting the "sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command" error.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed an error (I introduced a `:` instead of a `/`). Please try again.

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct either. It replaces literal character s instead of spaces.

Comment: I added the `-E` parameter in order to address all the regex statements. I also added the missing `:` special character.

Comment: Sorry, that's still not it. E.g. input string "MT100 domestic - wrong mapping of tag :20:
" becomes "MT100-dome-tic---wrong-mapping-of-tag-:20:". Any chance you might test locally first?

Comment: I tested it, but I suggest you to customize it as per your needs. It is so simple! :)

Comment: You can simplify this a lot while making it more robust, e.g. `sed -e 's/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]//g; s/\s\+/-/g;s/-$//'`. Strips unwanted chars, squashes spaces into hyphens, and removes any trailing hyphen (since I'm guessing they're unwanted). You don't need to run sed N times to execute N commands anyhow (and `-E` should be `-e`).

Comment: Dont't forget Bash has built-in substitution support

Comment: You can pass sed multiple " -e '<expression>' ", so you don't need the repeated " | sed ".